# will Cario Dock install as a desktop environment on CLI

Tags: command-line, 14.04, cairo

I'm somewhat new to linux and still learning.  I am running 14.04 CLI and want to add a desktop now.  Will Cairo Dock act as the desktop or do I need to install a different DE first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cairo Dock by itself is just a panel. You will need a window manager as well, such as OpenBox (used by LXDE), xfwm4 (used by XFCE), etc. These two are lightweight and should be enough to get you started. Also have a look at [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/502205/158442). For some more suggestions on windows managers, have a look [the Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_managers). The Arch Wiki article on [`xinitrc`](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Window_managers) is a starting point for starting X without a display manager like `lightdm`.

Answer (score 0):

Currently you need to install a desktop environment, as while it does display as a DE, it does not have a functioning window manager so it might display applications but it wouldn't be usable as a DE.

Comment: Thanks, recommendations?  I'm looking for minimal content but functionality.

Comment: I'm just going to flat out recommend kde, if you disable most of the effects it is about as fast on old hardware as lxde and offers a huge amount of customization options, though configuring it isn't going to be instantaneous and it takes a bit of patience to get it just right. If you need something to work out of the box then get lxde or xfce, though cinnamon is relatively fast you can't independently really download a fully stable version

Comment: which answer do you prefer? if you could set one as "the one" it would go towards making a difference in the unanswered ratio